# dbus c: what bindings (gdbus?) and client/server simple example

Tags: c, dbus

I would like to use dbus for communication between applications (actually I'm using a localhost socket).
I'm searching for a very basic (but complete/compilable) working example, so googleing around I found that the low level api is not to use because it is better to use bindings, dbus-glib bindings have some documentation but are also not to use because now there's the new gdbus (dbus integrated in glib) since version 2.26.
about gdbus except for the api http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus-convenience.html I cannot find any mini tutorial/minimal working example.
Can anybody help me out with this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a short [tutorial](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.30/ch29.html) which is mainly focused on how to migrate to GDBus from the low-level dbus-glib. However, there are some fairly good examples which helped me.

If you are using GObject, you can expose your object to GDBus fairly easy without messing with any code generation from xml. (see the tutorial above)

Comment: You're welcome. Just ask if there is something unclear. (and if you find it helping, don't forget to "praise" me) ;)

Comment: I didn't have time for it yet, for now I'm still going with the localhost socket that is already implemented and works. I'll let you know when I'll go through the tutorial you linked.

Comment: Hails savior Niklas Hansson! What is the linker option?

Comment: On vacation, will get back to you when I have access to my makefile.

Comment: dead link, making this answer useless

Comment: Since the question is rather big, the answer will be rather extensive as well. I'll see your request with an updated link.